# Is there any way to create skew animation for a View with ObjectAnimator in android

Tags: android, animation, android-view, skew, objectanimator

I want to create skew animation for a View in android.
So, I have rectangular view (this is normal/start state), at the end it should looks like this:
[image]

I can do such a thing with `android.view.animation` package using [Transformation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Transformation.html) of `TYPE_MATRIX`. So I can create `Matrix` and use `preSkew` method, apply this `Matrix` to my custom animation and then start this animation on a view. So this is OK.

**BUT**

The problem is I want to do this with `ObjectAnimator`.
Because using `android.view.animation` package is not recommended to use.
But I can't get the solution for this problem with `ObjectAnimator` class.

If I have `ImageView`, I can use method `setImageMatrix` for `ObjectAnimator` (and also create custom `MatrixEvaluator` to evaluate corresponding matrices for each factor),
but I want to get solution for this problem with a `View` class, not for some subclass of it.
And the main reason is, that `TextView`, for example, doesn't have public method like `setMatrix`, and I want to get the solution for `TextView` too. So get the solution for base View class is the main desire.

There is another solution: create custom, for example, `SkewTextView`, in which `onDraw` method we use `canvas.skew` method.

But this is worse solution even than using `android.view.animation` package, because you need to create wrappers for any `View` subclass you want to skew.

So, I don't know, how I can skew `View` with a `ObjectAnimator` (as `View` class doesn't have public methods like `setSkew` or `setMatrix`).

How would you solve this problem?
Have you any idea of how to solve this problem?
Is there a solution for this problem with `ObjectAnimator`?

Any help (or even thoughts) is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Actually, why do you think that it's not recommended to use Animation for this? Animators are better when you when you need to update View's position (or its properties) as well but if you only need to make some visible but not touchable change, why not use an Animation?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. OK, animations from android.view.animation package aren't deprecated for now and I can use them, but it seems that they will be deprecated later (this is my opinion). So, because of this I try to avoid using animations from android.view.animation package. So, my question is something about research: what should I do, if animations from android.view.animation are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Well without subclassing this might be a bit tricky. My main idea is to use [TimeAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeAnimator.html), which will provide you time callbacks in conjunction with [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) (which can use Matrix transformations). Or  you can use TimeAnimator and make a Bitmap from the View you want to skew, make the original View invisible, and draw the Bitmap on each TimeAnimator step applying a Matrix to it. But I'm not sure if this is the optimal way to do that, since you will have to create a new Bitmap on each frame

EDIT: No, Camera approach is not the way to do that as it is stated in comments below

Comment: There are some problems with this: 1) Camera doesn't provide nor methods for skewing transformation matrix nor for setting already skewed matrix instance 2) even if these methods are provided, there will be no way to apply this camera to View, except applying to canvas instance in onDraw method, but if I granted access there, I can call postSkew() etc. methods on canvas directly without Camera. And changing onDraw() method isn't a way to skew View from outside. But anyway, thank you for your thoughts)

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad. Camera approach definitely won't work, there might be some problems with the second one as well, but at least I'm quite sure that it'll work, however I don't actually expect Animation class to be deprecated

Answer (score 1):

[image: Skew Animation]

I created a **skew animation** using **Android Property Animation** APIs in my project (**[GitHub Link](https://github.com/vhow/animation)**).

What I did:

- Created a custom view ([SkewView](https://github.com/vhow/animation/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/io/github/vhow/animation/util/SkewView.java)) and added a `SKEW_X` property to it.

```
public class SkewView extends ImageView {
    private static final String TAG = "SkewView";

    public static final Property SKEW_X 
                = new FloatProperty("skewX") {
                    @Override
                    public void setValue(SkewView object, float value) {
                        object.setSkewX(value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Float get(SkewView object) {
                        return object.getSkewX();
                    }
                };

    private float mSkewX;

    // ...

    public float getSkewX() {
        return mSkewX;
    }

    public void setSkewX(float skewX) {
        mSkewX = skewX;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mSkewX != 0) {
            canvas.skew((float) (mSkewX * Math.PI / 180.0f), 0);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

- Used `ObjectAnimator` to animate this property.

```
ObjectAnimator skewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget, SkewView.SKEW_X, 30);
```